# Separating positive and negative values in R data.table (many columns)

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, magrittr

I was wondering how I could split many columns by their sign in a data.table. To be concrete, suppose that we have:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = c(-1,-2,1,3),
                z = c(-1,-1,-1,-1))
```

I am looking to create a new data.table called `DT_new` such that it looks like:

```
 DT_new
    x  z x_pos x_neg z_pos z_neg
1: -1 -1     0     1     0     1
2: -2 -1     0     2     0     1
3:  1 -1     1     0     0     1
4:  3 -1     3     0     0     1
```

The reason I am doing this is that I want to separate out the positive and negative variables in a regression. Doing a few of these manually is easy enough. But I have hundreds of variables that I want to apply this technique to. So I am hoping that there is a "SDcols" solutions.

Thanks!

Comment: Is a `dplyr` solution as an alternative accepted or only `data.table`. `dplyr` is in your tags.

Comment: Anything works, but preferably a data.table solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use .SDcols ;-) Please find below a reprex:

- Code

```r
DT[,`:=` (x_pos = fifelse(x>0, x, 0),
          x_neg = fifelse(x<0, abs(x), 0),
          z_pos = fifelse(z>0, z, 0),
          z_neg = fifelse(z<0, abs(z), 0))][]
```

- Output

```r
    x  z x_pos x_neg z_pos z_neg
1: -1 -1     0     1     0     1
2: -2 -1     0     2     0     1
3:  1 -1     1     0     0     1
4:  3 -1     3     0     0     1
```

---

**AS A FOLLOW-UP TO YOUR COMMENT**

Please find the reprex below.

- Code

```r
vars <- c("x","z")
suffix <- c("_pos", "_neg")

DT[, CJ(vars, suffix, sorted = FALSE)[, paste0(vars, suffix)] := .(fifelse(x>0, x, 0),
                                                                   fifelse(x<0, abs(x), 0), 
                                                                   fifelse(z>0, z, 0),
                                                                   fifelse(z<0, abs(z), 0))][]
```

- Output

```r
#>     x  z x_pos x_neg z_pos z_neg
#> 1: -1 -1     0     1     0     1
#> 2: -2 -1     0     2     0     1
#> 3:  1 -1     1     0     0     1
#> 4:  3 -1     3     0     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This works great. But if I may ask, is there a way to modify the above code to simply input a vector vars = c("x","z") and then create these _pos and _neg columns? The reason is that I need to do the above on 100s of variables. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @plausibly_exogenous, please find above an edit to answer your request. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```r
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = c(-1,-2,1,3),
                z = c(-1,-1,-1,-1))

col_nms <- c('x', 'z')
pos_nms <- paste0(col_nms, '_pos')
neg_nms <- paste0(col_nms, '_neg')

DT[, c(pos_nms) := lapply(.SD, function(.x) fifelse(.x > 0, .x, 0)), .SDcols = c('x', 'z')]
DT[, c(neg_nms) := lapply(.SD, function(.x) fifelse(.x < 0, -.x, 0)), .SDcols = c('x', 'z')]

DT
#>     x  z x_pos z_pos x_neg z_neg
#> 1: -1 -1     0     0     1     1
#> 2: -2 -1     0     0     2     1
#> 3:  1 -1     1     0     0     1
#> 4:  3 -1     3     0     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This works great. But if I may ask, is there a way to modify the above code to simply input a vector `vars = c("x","z")` and then create these `_pos` and `_neg` columns? The reason is that I need to do the above on 100s of variables. Thank you!

Comment: I think that yes, does the names have a pattern? e.g they start with the same prefix? Are a-z letters?

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous i edited the code with a preliminary solution.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `across` with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~case_when(
    . < 0 ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ .), .names = "{col}_pos")) %>% 
  mutate(across(-contains("pos"), ~case_when(
    . < 0 ~ abs(.),
    TRUE ~ 0), .names = "{col}_neg"))
```

```
    x  z x_pos z_pos x_neg z_neg
1: -1 -1     0     0     1     1
2: -2 -1     0     0     2     1
3:  1 -1     1     0     0     1
4:  3 -1     3     0     0     1
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x = c(-1,-2,1,3),
                z = c(-1,-1,-1,-1))

vars <- names(DT)

DT <- DT[, sapply(.SD, function(j){
  list(ifelse(j<0, 0, j), 
       ifelse(j>0, 0, j))
})]

setnames(DT, paste(rep(vars, each=2), c("_pos", "_neg"), sep=""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another dplyr option

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
DT <- data.table(x = c(-1, -2, 1, 3),
                 z = c(-1, -1, -1, -1))

DT %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), list(
    pos = ~ if_else(. > 0, ., 0),
    neg = ~ if_else(. < 0, -., 0)
  )))
#>     x  z x_pos x_neg z_pos z_neg
#> 1: -1 -1     0     1     0     1
#> 2: -2 -1     0     2     0     1
#> 3:  1 -1     1     0     0     1
#> 4:  3 -1     3     0     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you want to use this syntax but do data.table operations under the hood, you can use `tidytable`.

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidytable, warn.conflicts = F)
DT <- data.table(x = c(-1, -2, 1, 3),
                 z = c(-1, -1, -1, -1))

DT %>%
  mutate.(across.(everything(), list(
    pos = ~ if_else(. > 0, ., 0),
    neg = ~ if_else(. < 0, -., 0)
  )))
#> # A tidytable: 4 × 6
#>       x     z x_pos x_neg z_pos z_neg
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    -1    -1     0     1     0     1
#> 2    -2    -1     0     2     0     1
#> 3     1    -1     1     0     0     1
#> 4     3    -1     3     0     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>